# How do I add a background behind my page number with fancyhdr?

Tags: graphics, fancyhdr, backgrounds

I currently try to set my page number via:

```
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(1.5cm,-0.9cm){\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{page-number}}}\put(1.5cm,-0.9cm){\makebox[0pt]{\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}}\end{picture}}%
\fancyfoot[LE]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-1.5cm,-0.9cm){\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{page-number}}}\put(-1.5cm,-0.9cm){\makebox[0pt]{\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}}\end{picture}}%
```

But I get the error:

```
! You can't use `\raise' in vertical mode.
\put  ...itsset \@tempdimc {#2}\unitlength \raise 
                                                  \@tempdimc \hb@xt@ \z@ {\@...

l.41 ...makebox[0pt]{\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}}
                                                  \end{picture}}%
?
```

How do I either fix my code or use another way to get the a background right behind the page number that's centered the same way as the page number?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.125in,paperheight=9.25in,inner=2.0625cm,outer=3.2985cm,top=2.325cm,bottom=3.6846000000000005cm]{geometry}%
%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{changepage}%
\usepackage{ebgaramond}%
\newfontfamily{\pagenumberfont}{Pacifico}%
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}%

\usepackage[pdfusetitle,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\ifodd\value{page}\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{../right-\thechapter}\else\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{../raw_images/PoeticHypnosisI/left-\thechapter}\fi}}%%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(1.5cm,-0.9cm){\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{page-number}}}\put(1.5cm,-0.9cm){\makebox[0pt]{\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}}\end{picture}}%
\fancyfoot[LE]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-1.5cm,-0.9cm){\includegraphics[width = 1cm]{page-number}}}\put(-1.5cm,-0.9cm){\makebox[0pt]{\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}}\end{picture}}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}%

\newpage%
\begingroup%
\begin{adjustwidth}{0.75cm}{0.4cm}%
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{../tableofcontents}}}%
\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen%
\tableofcontents%
\end{adjustwidth}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}%
\endgroup%
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}%
\chapter*{Introduction}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}%
\vfill%
\paragraph{}%

%
Super Text
\paragraph{}%

%
Super Text

%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to provide a complete compilable document. That's much more useful than code snippets.

Comment: @cfr : I tried to cut down to a minimal example and added it.

Comment: Why are you loading conflicting font packages? If you want to use `T1` and `lmodern`, don't use `fontspec`. If you want to use `fontspec`, ditch `fontenc`, `lmodern`, `textcomp` and `inputenc`. When creating MWEs, try not to depend on things some people don't have unless they're essential to the problem e.g. Pacifico and specific images.

Comment: your example can't be used for a test. You are loading a local font and local images. Replace them by example images from the mwe package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example can't be used as it is. I've replaced your images with standard example images. You're also loading conflicting fonts and font packages. Since I don't have the font you're using for page numbers anyway, I've commented out the `fontspec` stuff and gone with the `fontenc`/`inputenc`/`lmodern`/`textcomp` stuff. If you want to use `fontspec` for that font, remove the incompatible packages and uncomment the relevant lines.

## Original

The simplest way I know to achieve the effect you want is to put things in boxes and then use them in the footer setup. Here, I've used 'coffins' from `xcoffins` because they are easy to join and align. This makes it straightforward to put the page number on top of the image and does away with the need to use `picture` and fiddle with horizontal/vertical adjustments manually.

[image: output with sample images]

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.125in,paperheight=9.25in,inner=2.0625cm,outer=3.2985cm,top=2.325cm,bottom=3.6846000000000005cm]{geometry}%
%
\usepackage[]{graphicx}%
\usepackage{xcoffins}
% \usepackage{fontspec}% if you want to use this, remove fontenc, inputenc, lmodern, textcomp
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{changepage}%
\usepackage{ebgaramond}%
% \newfontfamily{\pagenumberfont}{Pacifico}%
% \setmainfont{EB Garamond}%
\let\pagenumberfont\sffamily
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}% load last unless specific package requires later loading, consider bookmarks
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\ifodd\value{page}\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-a}\else\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-b}\fi}}

\NewCoffin \PagenumberCoffin
\NewCoffin \PagenumberbackCoffin

\NewDocumentCommand \MakePagenumberCoffin { O {r} }
{%
  \SetHorizontalCoffin \PagenumberCoffin {\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}%
  \SetHorizontalCoffin \PagenumberbackCoffin {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}%
  \JoinCoffins \PagenumberbackCoffin [hc,vc] \PagenumberCoffin [hc,vc]%
  \TypesetCoffin \PagenumberbackCoffin [B,#1]%
}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{\MakePagenumberCoffin}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\MakePagenumberCoffin[l]}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}%
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0.75cm}{0.4cm}%
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-c}}}%
    \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen
    \tableofcontents
  \end{adjustwidth}%
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
\endgroup
% \setmainfont{EB Garamond}%
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}%
\vfill

\paragraph{This command is not the way to make paragraphs}%

Super Text
\paragraph{A subsubsubheading} rather than a paragraph.

This is a new paragraph.

Super Text is in another new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

## Edit 1 (Non-experimental)

If you prefer to avoid the experimental `xcoffins`, here's a non-experimental version.

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.125in,paperheight=9.25in,inner=2.0625cm,outer=3.2985cm,top=2.325cm,bottom=3.6846000000000005cm]{geometry}%
%
\usepackage[]{graphicx}%
% \usepackage{fontspec}% if you want to use this, remove fontenc, inputenc, lmodern, textcomp
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{changepage}%
\usepackage{ebgaramond}%
% \newfontfamily{\pagenumberfont}{Pacifico}%
% \setmainfont{EB Garamond}%
\let\pagenumberfont\sffamily
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}% load last unless specific package requires later loading, consider bookmarks
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\ifodd\value{page}\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-a}\else\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-b}\fi}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_christian_pageno_coffin
\coffin_new:N \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin

\AtBeginDocument
{
  \hcoffin_gset:Nn \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin { \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \MakePagenumberCoffin { O {r} }
{%
  \group_begin:
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_christian_pageno_coffin  {\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}
    \coffin_set_eq:NN \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin
    \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin { hc } { vc } \l_christian_pageno_coffin { hc } { vc } { 0pt } { 0pt }
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin { B } { #1 } { 0pt } { 0pt }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{\MakePagenumberCoffin}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\MakePagenumberCoffin[l]}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}%
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0.75cm}{0.4cm}%
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-c}}}%
    \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen
    \tableofcontents
  \end{adjustwidth}%
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
\endgroup
% \setmainfont{EB Garamond}%
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}%
\vfill

\paragraph{This command is not the way to make paragraphs}%

Super Text
\paragraph{A subsubsubheading} rather than a paragraph.

This is a new paragraph.

Super Text is in another new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

This has the advantage of typesetting the image into the background coffin only once. After that the result is reused each time. The high-level commands in `xcoffins` don't let you just copy one coffin to another, but the commands in the programming layer are more full-featured.

## Edit 2 (With shift)

We can modify this to shift the page numbers by adding a basic key-value interface. Three keys are provided

- `side` should be `l` or `r` (default: `r`)
- `xshift` should be a dimension (default: `1.5cm`)
- `yshift` should be a dimension (default: `-0.9cm`)

Then the following will shift the left page numbers left and down and the right page numbers down and right.

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.125in,paperheight=9.25in,inner=2.0625cm,outer=3.2985cm,top=2.325cm,bottom=3.6846000000000005cm]{geometry}%
%
\usepackage[]{graphicx}%
% \usepackage{fontspec}% if you want to use this, remove fontenc, inputenc, lmodern, textcomp
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{changepage}%
\usepackage{ebgaramond}%
% \newfontfamily{\pagenumberfont}{Pacifico}%
% \setmainfont{EB Garamond}%
\let\pagenumberfont\sffamily
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}% load last unless specific package requires later loading, consider bookmarks
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\ifodd\value{page}\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-a}\else\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-b}\fi}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_christian_pageno_coffin
\coffin_new:N \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin

\AtBeginDocument
{
  \hcoffin_gset:Nn \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin { \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} }
}

\keys_define:nn { christian / page~no }
{
  side .tl_set:N = \l_christian_side_tl,
  side .initial:n = r,
  xshift .dim_set:N = \l_christian_xshift_dim,
  xshift .initial:n = 1.5cm,
  yshift .dim_set:N = \l_christian_yshift_dim,
  yshift .initial:n = -0.9cm,
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn { NnVVV }
\NewDocumentCommand \MakePagenumberCoffin { O {side=r,xshift=1.5cm} }
{%
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { christian / page~no } { #1 }
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_christian_pageno_coffin  {\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}
    \coffin_set_eq:NN \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin
    \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin { hc } { vc } \l_christian_pageno_coffin { hc } { vc } { 0pt } { 0pt }
    \coffin_typeset:NnVVV \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin { B } \l_christian_side_tl \l_christian_xshift_dim \l_christian_yshift_dim
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{\MakePagenumberCoffin}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\MakePagenumberCoffin[side=l,xshift=-1.5cm]}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}%
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0.75cm}{0.4cm}%
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-c}}}%
    \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen
    \tableofcontents
  \end{adjustwidth}%
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
\endgroup
% \setmainfont{EB Garamond}%
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}%
\vfill

\paragraph{This command is not the way to make paragraphs}%

Super Text
\paragraph{A subsubsubheading} rather than a paragraph.

This is a new paragraph.

Super Text is in another new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image: shifted page numbers]

## Edit 3

If you just want the page numbers offset, then all the fiddling about with shifting things is needless. Instead, you can simply redefine `\headwidth` as explained in `fancyhdr`'s documentation. This is straightforward. So all you need really is the way to box the page number on its background.

[image: standard case of off-setting covered in fancyhdr docs combined with coffins to 'box' (and a bit) the page number combination]

Note that the lines are just from `show frame` for demonstration purposes. Remove from the commented `geometry` line for actual use.

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[show frame,paperwidth=6.125in,paperheight=9.25in,inner=2.0625cm,outer=3.2985cm,top=2.325cm,bottom=3.6846000000000005cm]{geometry}% remove "show frame" when happy with layout
%
\usepackage[]{graphicx}%
\usepackage{tocloft}%
\usepackage{ebgaramond}%
\usepackage{changepage}
\let\pagenumberfont\sffamily
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}% load last unless specific package requires later loading, consider bookmarks
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt, -\paperheight) {\ifodd\value{page}\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-a}\else\includegraphics[width =\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{example-image-b}\fi}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_christian_pageno_coffin
\coffin_new:N \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin

\AtBeginDocument
{
  \hcoffin_gset:Nn \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin { \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} }
}

\keys_define:nn { christian / page~no }
{
  side .tl_set:N = \l_christian_side_tl,
  side .initial:n = r,
  yshift .dim_set:N = \l_christian_yshift_dim,
  yshift .initial:n = -0.9cm,
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn { NnVnV }
\NewDocumentCommand \MakePagenumberCoffin { O {side=r,xshift=1.5cm} }
{% if textblock has constant width, we could do this more efficiently by setting some of this only once for each of the two even/odd pages, but we don't want to assume that
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { christian / page~no } { #1 }
    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_christian_pageno_coffin  {\pagenumberfont\Large\thepage}
    \coffin_set_eq:NN \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin \g_christian_pagenoback_coffin
    \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin { hc } { vc } \l_christian_pageno_coffin { hc } { vc } { 0pt } { 0pt }
    \coffin_typeset:NnVnV \l_christian_pagenocombo_coffin { B } \l_christian_side_tl { 0pt } \l_christian_yshift_dim
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[RO]{\MakePagenumberCoffin[side=r]}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\MakePagenumberCoffin[side=l]}
\addtolength \headwidth {1.5cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}%
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0.75cm}{0.4cm}%
    \tableofcontents
  \end{adjustwidth}%
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
\endgroup
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}%
\vfill

\paragraph{This command is not the way to make paragraphs}%

Super Text
\paragraph{A subsubsubheading} rather than a paragraph.

This is a new paragraph.

Super Text is in another new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Package `xcoffins` does not seem to be directly available. Instead, part of `l3experimental` ?

Comment: @rallg It's distributed as part of TeX Live, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be 'directly available'.

Comment: @rallg See edit. I've added a non-experimental version.

Comment: Thanks, it does manage to include the picture the right way. However, the positioning I had of "1.5cm,-0.9cm" is not included and it's not clear how to integrate it into the code given that it is "1.5cm,-0.9cm" on the right and "-1.5cm,-0.9cm" on the left.

Comment: @Christian That is easy to adjust. Where is it 1.5/0.9 cm from exactly? (Note, I don't mean 'that is easy to adjust if this stuff is new to you', but it is easy to adjust if you've done this before.)

Comment: @Christian See edit. Let me know if I'm wrong about where they're meant to shift to. The code currently shifts the left numbers left, the right right and both down.

Comment: I chose the number of 1.5/0.9 cm based on what fits well with the background images I'm having. In the images you posted B has the correct distances to the outer border but the distance on the right page in C/A to the outer border is bigger and not what would be gotten by 1.5 in my initial code.

Comment: @Christian Your initial code produced an error, so I'm not sure what you mean. 1.5cm from the outer border of *what*?

Comment: @cfr : I want the difference between the page number and the outer border of the page to be the same for the left and right page. Most books have this symmetrical where the distance between the pagenumber and the outer border is the same for both the right and left page.

Comment: @Christian That case is much simpler. I use it myself to produce course packets. You can just use the method in `fancyhdr`'s manual and extend `\headwidth`. Then all the fiddling about is unnecessary and only the page number/image combination remains to do. See latest edit above. This is why it's really important to provide people with code which they can compile. In this case, current (non-erroneous) output with a couple of arrows would have saved a lot of trouble.